# machine learning system with similar features

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any solution for a machine learning system (regression or classification) with features which have very similar values? I mean there is no significant difference between the value of features we have.

Thank you..

Comment: Define very similar and significant difference. Have you tried any model that has failed? If so, which?

Comment: It's not clear what're you asking. What's the problem? Why do you need these features in the first place? Why not throw them away?

Comment: as you know, when the features are the same, it will be difficult to learn a model in order to distinguish different classes. because we need some features to differentiate classes in a classification system. but in the case of my question there is not such features and I wanna to do the classification task when all the features have similar values!

Comment: @FarhanehMoradi. if you have only one feature repeating it hundred of times won't help at all. You should delete identical features.

Comment: If there is not, in any sense, any meaningful distinction between your features, then your classification task is impossible. Your best options are A) Find subtle differences between features, perhaps in the way the interact with each other, or B) Find new features.

Comment: I don't have one feature, in fact the instances which i wanna classify are similar instances with similar feature values which describe them.